# LightGBM precision optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, precision, lightgbm

In LightGBM model from scikitLearn Python library, how precision (True Positives / (True Positives + False Positives)) can be optimized?

Comment: Split the data to train and test. Search for parameters that maximize precision in the test sample for example using GridSearchCV.